# PyQt6. ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: The specified procedure was not found

Tags: python, pyqt, dll, импорт

Установил питон. Скачал библиотеку PyQt6. Все по инструкции в корневой каталог. Я написал в консоли команду для проверки: «from PyQt6 import QtCore». Выдало ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2.5\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 364, in runcode
    coro = func()
           ^^^^^^
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.2.5\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: Не найдена указанная процедура.
```

Я перепробовал много советов. Ничего не помогло. Пожалуйста, помогите мне решить проблему.

Вот часть самих модулей:

1. `C:\...\pydevconsole.py`:

   ```
    def runcode(self, code):
        try:
            func = types.FunctionType(code, self.locals)
            coro = func()
            if inspect.iscoroutine(coro):
                loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
                loop.run_until_complete(coro)
        except SystemExit:
            raise
   ```
2. `C:\...\pydev_import_hook.py`:

   ```
    def do_import(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        activate_func = None
        if name in self._modules_to_patch:
            activate_func = self._modules_to_patch[name]

        module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
        try:
            if activate_func and not self.inside_activation:
                self.inside_activation = True
                succeeded = activate_func()
                if succeeded and name in self._modules_to_patch:
                    # Remove if only it was executed correctly
                    self._modules_to_patch.pop(name)
                self.inside_activation = False
        except:
            sys.stderr.write("Matplotlib support failed\n")
            traceback.print_exc()
        return module
   ```

Comment: 1. [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119) 2. переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: Проверьте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77585434/python-pyqt6-dll-load-failed

Answer (score 1):

Удалите все модули, имеющие отношение к PyQt6, но через **PowerShell**:

```
pip3 uninstall -y PyQt6 pyqt6-plugins PyQt6-Qt6 PyQt6-sip pyqt6-tools qt6-applications qt6-tools
```

Переустановите PyQt6:

```
pip3 install PyQt6
```

Comment: Ураа! Спасибо огромное! Видимо просто нужно было вместо pip написать pip3